# ForLookup not working from multiple columns

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am looking at trying to generate a for loop to pull data from 30 fields based on a lookup table.

I can't get the code below to work on multiple columns but does work on one column do i need to have one for each of the 30 columns in the data extension or can i build this in one?

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue1 = subtype1
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("PH_Product_Name_Lookup",@numRowsToReturn,"Old_Product_Name",Subtype", @lookupValue1)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @old_Product_Name, @new_Product_Name
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @old_Product_Name = field(@row,"old_Product_Name")
set @new_Product_Name = field(@row,"new_Product_Name")

]%%

old product: %%=v(@old_Product_Name)=%%
<br><br>
new product: %%=v(@new_Product_Name)=%%

%%[

next @i 

ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a double-quote next to `subType`.  If you want to retrieve the other columns, just add the additional fields, like this:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue1 = subtype1
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("PH_Product_Name_Lookup",@numRowsToReturn, "Old_Product_Name", "Subtype", @lookupValue1)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        var @old_Product_Name, @new_Product_Name, @field3, @field4, @field4
        set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
        set @old_Product_Name = field(@row,"old_Product_Name")
        set @new_Product_Name = field(@row,"new_Product_Name")
        set @field3 = field(@row,"field3")
        set @field4 = field(@row,"field4")
        set @field5 = field(@row,"field5")

        ]%%

        old product: %%=v(@old_Product_Name)=%%
        <br><br>
        new product: %%=v(@new_Product_Name)=%%

        %%[

    next @i 

ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: thanks, how do I add the new_product_name to the loop as its only showing me the old_product_name

Comment: I have had to create 30 loops as i have 30 subtype codes as there could be 30 product that i need to populate a table with and cant find the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Adam's answer, if you have 30 subtypes you could just do a nested for-next loop to loop through all the subtypes, something like this:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i, @c

for @c = 1 to 30 do
    set @lookupValue1 = concat("subtype", @c)
    set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("PH_Product_Name_Lookup",@numRowsToReturn, "Old_Product_Name", "Subtype", @lookupValue1)
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

    if @rowCount > 0 then

        for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        var @old_Product_Name, @new_Product_Name, @field3, @field4, @field4
        set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
        set @old_Product_Name = field(@row,"old_Product_Name")
        set @new_Product_Name = field(@row,"new_Product_Name")
        set @field3 = field(@row,"field3")
        set @field4 = field(@row,"field4")
        set @field5 = field(@row,"field5")

        ]%%

        old product: %%=v(@old_Product_Name)=%%
        <br><br>
        new product: %%=v(@new_Product_Name)=%%

        %%[

        next @i 
    ENDIF
next @c
]%%
```

This assumes that your subtypes are all increments of subtype1, but could be modified with regex to match naming conventions.